# How can I create Monthly Archive list on Sidebar in Gatsby blog?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

can somebody help me to create monthly archive list on Sidebar in my Gatsby blog ?

As I am relatively new in Gatsby, any suggestion/comments are highly appreciated !

**What I would like to achieve is here**
[Year Month (number of posts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyqdM.png)

I would like to list the 'year month' and 'number of posts' those which are posted in corresponding period, in Sidebar.

What I have done so far is creating 'PeriodList' component as below.

**PeriodList component**

```
import React from "react"
import kebabCase from 'lodash/kebabCase'
import './style.scss'
import { Link, StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const PeriodList = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allMarkdownRemark(limit: 2000) {
          group(field: frontmatter___date) {
            fieldValue
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <nav>
        <h1 className="periodlist-header">月別アーカイブ</h1>
        <ul className="period-list">
          {data.allMarkdownRemark.group.map(date => (
                <li className="period-list-item" key={date.fieldValue}>
                     <span className="period-list-icon"></span>
                     <Link className="period-list-item-link" to={`/${kebabCase(date.fieldValue)}/`}>
                         {date.fieldValue} ({date.totalCount})
                     </Link>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )}
  />
)

export default PeriodList
```

As a result, I got the list below.
[current list of archive in sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD9co.png)

It lists each post by date.

Can somebody support me how to show 'year month' and 'number of posts' for corresponding period in sidebar ?

Thank you so much for your support always and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to convert your `data.allMarkdownRemark.group` ARRAY before rendering ... it's just js

Your code is shortened - returns JSX directly `render={data => ( JSX structure` - but you can extend rendering 'flow' with any js you need that way:

```
// render takes a function
render={data => { 
  // js body here - any calculations/convertion needed 
  // to adapt your data to your rendering needs (`.map()`, `.reduce()`, etc.)
  const monthGrouppedData = someConvertDataFn(data.allMarkdownRemark.group);
  // return JSX
  return ( 
    {monthGrouppedData.map(month => ...`
```

Comment: Thank you @xadm !
This is the direction that I was looking for !
And, I could make monthly archive component as below thanks to your support.
https://kinnikumegane.com/posts/transformgatsbytowordpresslike9/